# Salesforce: Audit Log In/Log Out Time

Tags: user, login

Is there a way to audit how long a user was logged in to Salesforce.

I see the login time but not the logout time.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the Login and Logout events via the REST-API. These resources could be useful for you:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_event_log_file_query.htm